# guidance for htaccess rewrite 301 rules

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have been struggling to get rewrite 301 rules to work. I need to maintain the existing file structure but simplify the URLs for the benefit of Google etc.

the existing file is

- www.mydomain.com/abc/index.php

I want to simplify this to

- wwww.mydomain.com/xyz.php

I have tried putting a rewrite rule in the root directory

```
RewriteRule ^xyz$ /abc/index.php [L,QSA]
```

and another rewrite rule in the /abc directory

Redirect 301 index.php /xyz.php

However this doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ^xyz$ does not match xyz.php, what url are you going to?

Comment: wwww.mydomain.com/xyz.php

Comment: All works now. Thanks for your guidance.